# I'm working on Euler 12 , the code i have seems to workes properly but too slow , very very slow. How can i modify it to run faster?

Tags: java, performance

Like i sad , i am working on Euler problem 12 https://projecteuler.net/problem=12 , i believe that this program will give the correct answer but is too slow , i tried to wait it out but even after 9min it still cant finish it. How can i modify it to run faster ?

```
package highlydivisibletriangularnumber_ep12;
public class HighlyDivisibleTriangularNumber_EP12 {

public static void findTriangular(int triangularNum){
    triangularValue = triangularNum * (triangularNum + 1)/2;
}

static long triangularValue = 0l;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long n = 1l;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while(true){
        findTriangular(i);
        while(n<=triangularValue){
            if(triangularValue%n==0){
                counter++;
            }
            n++;
        }
        if(counter>500){
            break;
        }else{
            counter = 0;
        }
        n=1;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(triangularValue);
}
}
```

Comment: "*this program will give the correct answer but is too slow*" - then this question belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow

Comment: Maybe, @Fureeish.  "I need a faster algorithm" is not necessarily off-topic for SO, nor necessarily *on*-topic for Code Review.  That a different algorithm works in some insufficient sense does not make it so.  Nevertheless, I would say that this particular question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Algorithmic improvement: count factors by counting the number of distinct combinations of the candidate numbers' prime factors (including multiplicity).  With a pre-computed list of primes, that should be a lot quicker than the scan you do now to count factors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right, but that's probably an overkill. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two simple tricks:

When `x%n == 0`, then also `x%m == 0` with `m = x/n`. This way you need to consider only `n <= Math.ceil(sqrt(x))`, which is a huge speed up. With each divisor smaller than the square root, you get another one for free. Beware of the case of equality. The speed gain is huge.

As your `x` is a product of two numbers `i` and `i+1`, you can generate all its divisors as product of the divisors of `i` and `i+1`. What makes it more complicated is the fact that in general, the same product can be created using different factors. Can it happen here? Do you need to generate products or can you just count them? Again, the speed gain is huge.

You could use prime factorization, but I'm sure, these tricks alone are sufficient.

Answer (score -3):

It appears to me that your algorithm is a bit too brute-force, and due to this, will consume an enormous amount of cpu time regardless of how you might rearrange it.

What is needed is an algorithm that implements a formula that calculates at least part of the solution, instead of brute-forcing the whole thing.

If you get stuck, you can use your favorite search engine to find a number of solutions, with varying degrees of efficiency.